# Why does inline-block element expand more than its content?

Tags: width, css

Take a look here: http://dabblet.com/gist/8d85e0e30b4d46e14654.

Why does the `span` element expand as if the two words were on the same line?
Is there a way to prevent that and have it wrap to the minimum width possible given by content size?

**EDIT:**
Using 'white-space:nowrap;` doesn't fix the issue.
I'm trying to make the span fit the text, not the text fit the span.
That's why the parent div has a fixed width.

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more?

Comment: Well, as you can see in the link, the background for the element is larger than its content.

Comment: For me its looking fine only. I am using chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome too. Do you not see the gray background larger than the text it is wrapping?

Comment: No. it is fit to that grey. Not exceeding anyway.

Comment: I will attack a screenshot.

Comment: Wait, the text fits yest, but the gray area is too large.

Comment: thats cool and give more idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/9D9PV/)**

```
span
{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#333333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
div
{
    width:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

for the span.

Try using `white-space: pre-line;`. It creates a line-break wherever a line-break appears in the code, but ignores the extra whitespace (tabs and spaces etc.).

Also reduce the width of the div.

link : http://jsfiddle.net/29nrr/

Comment: I want the text on 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
span
{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#333333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
div
{
    width:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the word doesn't have enough space to fill it there. If you enter exactly fit word it will not give any space. Ok i will come to the answer part. I am going to force the word to show as much as possible in that place then go to next line. How? Using the css property `word-break:break-all`.

```
 span
 {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#333333;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  word-break:break-all;
 }
```

Comment: The issue isn't that I want to break the word or make it one like. I want it to be as it is now, but have the parent container actually contain its content. inline-block elements are supposed to be as wide as their content.

Comment: If you dont want break the word, remove width from parent and assign it as max-width or assign width for the main div is 5px;

Comment: The parent div is larger than the span needs. I don't want to touch the parent. The issue here is that inline-block elements are supposed to be as wide as their content. Parent container doesn't influence width in this case.